# .net core wwwroot data folder - Do Not Copy being ignored

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

So I have a simple .net core application that I am deploying to Azure from VS2019.  I have some json files in the wwwroot\data folder and I have set them to content=none and copy="Do Not Copy".

However when I publish the still publish every time.

I have also edited the .csproj file and ensure this is there

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\data\file.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and yet it still publishes.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\data\file.json">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Nope, that seems to delete the target version every time on deploy.  I want to manually push it once and then never have it overwritten.

Comment: Please check if `Delete all existing files prior to publish` option is checked while you do deployment.